# Javascript What other tricks should i employ instead of exporting symbols

Tags: javascript, architecture, backbone.js, underscore.js

Google Closure library provides export symbols option to provide access to constructors through window object.

ex: export task will allows doing `window.task`

**BUT** this is totally far from Google closure library. I am using Backbone.js to construct a task application. My views,models, routers and split up in many files and i follow the above process to assign the instance, source to window object so that one can access another.

- How can i access models, views, routers for a single application not through window? What tricks, tips have you employed to make them kind of sandboxed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will almost always have to have at least one thing exposed in the window.

But, you can use namespaces to help out.

```
// app.js
var App = App || {};
App.Views = App.Views || {};
App.Models = App.Models || {};

App.Views.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({});
App.Model.User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

The only case in which you won't necessarily is if you are using requireJS.

```
// app.js
define(['views/home'], function (home) {
    var home = new home({
        el: '#home'
    });
});
// views/home.js
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    var home = Backbone.View.extend({});
    return home;        
});
```

Although, I suppose if you REALLY wanted to, you could do everything inside of a Self Executing Function.

```
(function ($, Backbone) {
    // Do your stuff here instead?.
    // Just keep in mind, nothing you do in here will be available outside.
    var home = Backbone.View.extend({});
    new home(); // Works...
}(jQuery, Backbone);
new home(); // FAIL!
```

The only problem with that is anything you do inside of the function is not available outside of it.

Let me know if you have any questions on any implementations.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you use - global scope (aka "window" in browser) or some other object to hold your namespaces, there always will be chance of collision. Using something else only frees you from minding what default properties window already have.

Best practice for any module is to expose to outside view (through window or whatever) only single object and have everything else as it properties, since that reduces possibility of collision to absolute minimum.